# invert matrix in matlab/sorting a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-inverse

I have this problem that I need to sort a matrix in MATLAB.

Input:(2x5 matrix)

```
1    2
3    4
5    6
7    8
9    10
```

And I'd like the output to be.(2x5)

```
9   10
7   8
5   6
3   4
1   2
```

I would like to invert first matrix, help is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flip the array upside down by using [`flipud`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html).

```
A = [1, 2; 3, 4; 5, 6; 7, 8; 9, 10];
B = flipud(A);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help.

Comment: @Asen Martin  is this a solution?  You said you want to "sort a matrix," which is in general different from `flipud`, although they are the same for your example.  It's not clear whether you want to sort each column individually, or as groups using `sortrows`.

Comment: @JeffIrwin that is a good point. The OP was using "invert" and "sort" both, along with a sample output. This answer is just my best interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

That's just some basic matrix indexing, using the [colon](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html?refresh=true) operator:

```
M(end:-1:1,:)
```